# Update multiple rows with 'CASE WHEN EXISTS' too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

i have this query

```
update t_reconcile_biller b set status = case when exists (
    SELECT i.credit_amount, i.recipt_no,  
    i.credit_acct_no, i.recon_date 
    FROM t_reconcile_t24 i 
    WHERE i.debit_acct_no = 'IDR1720600010001'
    and b.col_4 = i.credit_amount
    AND b.col_7 = i.recipt_no 
    AND b.col_2 = i.card_no 
    AND i.status <> 5 
) then 1 else 2 end
where b.status <> 5 AND b.file_name in ('20200923-bnf', '20200922-bnf')
AND b.col_13 = 'DESTIONATION' AND b.col_4 <> '0'
AND b.col_14 in ('A', 'FC')
```

which take 52 second to run with postgres, where t_reconcile_biller has 3.900 rows and t_reconcile_t24 has 32.000 rows.

How can i make this query faster and more efficient ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using

Answer (score 1):

The following index on the table appearing inside the exists clause might help:

```sql
CREATE INDEX rec_idx ON t_reconcile_t24 (
    credit_amount, recipt_no, card_no, status );
```

If used, Postgres could use the above index to quickly lookup each record in the target table.  In addition, the following index on the outer table might also be helpful:

```sql
CREATE INDEX biller_idx ON t_reconcile_biller (
    status, file_name, col_4, col_13, col_14 );
```

Comment: by the way, is that update query (in the topicstarter's post) optimized into left join? if not, then it means each row is checked against the whole "t24" table, isn't it (although it's hard to consider it as optimization if they don't have relevant indexes so basically they would still do the same thing)